# cannot use \textcolor in \title

Tags: color, titles, amsart

I need to color a portion of the title of an article, but I keep getting errors.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\title{  \protect\textcolor{red}{does not work in title}}
\maketitle
  \textcolor{red}{work here}
\end{document}
```

and here is the error, from the log file:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RED'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \maketitle
              
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

In case this matter, I am running pdflatex under Tex live 2022 in linux mint.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a protected command that hides `red` from the uppercasing

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\NewDocumentCommand\myred{m}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\title{\myred{does not work in title}}
\maketitle
  \textcolor{red}{work here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @carlisle:  I can confirm that it works.  Thanks!  Can you explain briefly WHY it works?  I must admit I never understood what \protect does, and how it does what it does; I throw it in everything I run into problems with \title, and pray that it works :-)

Comment: @underflow your problem is not that \textcolor breaks somehow, but that the red gets uppercased and the color RED does not exist.  You could also simply add `\colorlet{RED}{red}`.

Comment: the form of uppercasing used by amsart does not know that the argument `{red}` is any different from the argument`{your title}` so it uppercases both (so an alternative fix is to define the colour `RED`)  making it part of a command just hides it from the uppercase as long as you delay expanding the command until after the uppercasing (which is what  protection is about) @underflow

Answer (score 1):

You can do `\newcommand{\addred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}` and it will work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\addred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\title{It \addred{works} in the title}
\maketitle

It also \addred{works} here

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, since you don't know whether some package you employ loads `textcase`, it's convenient to add `\protect` for extra safety.

Explanation: by default, `amsart` does `\uppercase`, but if you have non ASCII characters in the title it might not work and `textcase` would come to the rescue; but it needs robust commands inside its argument.

```
\title{It \protect\addred{works} in the title}
```

or decide to make `\addred` robust, which can be done in different ways:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\addred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\addred}{m}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```